# How to remove common elements from both lists in python3.6?

Tags: python-3.6

If

```
L1=[2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8]
L2=[1,3,2,2,4]
```

then after performing the operation my result should be:

```
L1=[6,8,4,6,8]
L2=[1,3]
```

The operation should remove elements present in common in both List1 and List2. Tell me a method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

For less complexity I suggest:

```
uniq = set(L1).intersection(L2)
L1_uniq = [x for x in L1 if x not in uniq]
L2_uniq = [x for x in L2 if x not in uniq]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L1_unique=[i for i in L1 if i not in L2]
L2_unique=[i for i in L2 if i not in L1]
```

This is called `list comprehension`, which is a very useful feature of python. It makes use of `for` loop, which can be expressed explicitly as:

```
L1_unique=[]
for i in L1:
    if i not in L2:
        L1.append(i)
```

Which is equivalent to a double `for` loop:

```
for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
        if i==j:
            break
    else:
        L1_unique.append(i)
```

As the other answer presented (and I voted up), having a `set` based on the intersect of the two lists before list comprehension can reduce time complexity, because it ultimately reduces number of searches in the second list. (You can simply run %%timeit to see if you use IPython)

In principle, you may want to modify the structure of the second list, so that you do not have to traverse the entire list in case of unsuccessful search . But I doubt if it can be faster than list comprehension in practice.

Comment: Can I have a better method which reduces complexity?

Comment: @AishwaryaAishu In terms of length of codes I do not know anything shorter than list comprehension. In terms of time complexity, its worst-case is n square and the best-case is linear. What exactly do you mean by "reducing complexity"?

Comment: @Austin Yes you are right, I tried my best to explain. But what is OP?

Comment: Original Poster - the one who asked the question.